# Story with a Tyrannosaurus Rex that has an elephant-like trunk

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, dinosaurs, choose-your-own-adventure

I read this book when I was a pre-teen, definitely before 1988 and probably before 1984, in English, in the USA.

I think that the book may have been some sort of "Choose Your Own Adventure" or "Pick a Path" book, maybe even a "Time Machine" story.  It's definitely not from a Gamma World RPG novel or TSR product, although it may have shared some stylistic elements.

The only thing I really remember from the story is that the main character (a young or teenaged boy) was walking through an ancient overgrown forest/jungle, and he encountered a Tyrannosaurus Rex that had a long trunk, like an elephant.

I think there may have been an illustration, too, showing the creature, but I'm not certain of that.

I don't think that the creature featured prominently in the tale;  as best as I can recall it was a brief throwaway encounter, the creature showed up, scared the main character, then was never seen again -- although I suppose I should say that I'm not sure about that either.

I'm sorry that there's so little to go on, but it's my hope that a "T-Rex with an elephant-like trunk" is a memorable enough detail to ring a bell for somebody.

Comment: Could you add a few more details, even if they sound irrelevant? It would greatly help us in identifying it, @AlexBates .

Comment: @HarryWeasley - if I knew any more details, I'd post them!

I'm fairly sure that the protagonist was a teenage boy, but I can't swear to it.  I'm also fairly sure that he was alone, but, I'm not sure about that, either.  It *might* have been about time travel or dimensional travel, but I'm very uncertain about that - it might have been a post-apocalyptic tale, too.  I asked on a Gamma World page, and was pointed to the "Delta Fragment" sourcebook as having guys in power armor fighting T-Rexes, but, nobody could tell me if there was a T Rex with a trunk in it.  I'm still looking.

Comment: Yeah, I did search the net, but nothing definitive turned up. Still searching!

Comment: Interesting bit of follow-up - I posted this question on a Gamma World page, and James Ward himself (the creator of Gamma World!) commented to say that it was definitely not a TSR or Gamma World product.  So, that eliminates some possibilities.  I do still think that it may have had a "Gamma World" (lots of weird mutants everywhere) sort of style to it, but if so it was not specifically a TSR or Gamma World product.

Answer (score 8):

I believe that this is [*Cosmic Encounters*](https://gamebooks.org/Item/3171/Show) by R.G. Austin.

[image]

> *You tremble when you realize that you are standing next to a gigantic beast that has the body of Tyrannosaurus rex and the head and trunk of a monstrous elephant. Its tusks are five feet long and its red eyes are glaring."*

The above is the only Google Books search result I can find when doing searches like "tyrannosaurus elephant trunk" inside that book. Which fits with your remembering it as just a one-off encounter.

Its first printing was in 1982, so that would fit with your reading it "probably before 1984".

[image] [image] [image]